# How to RedirectToPage to ChangePassword in razor pages identity

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I can't use RedirectToPage for any of the pages in the identity folder in my razor pages app.

If I use:  `return RedirectToPage("/Identity/Account/Manage/ChangePassword");`

What I got is an error:

*InvalidOperationException: No page named '/Identity/Account/Manage/ChangePassword' matches the supplied values.*

In the case of using Redirect itself, routing works fine but I need to route some values so I have to use RedirectToPage

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use RedirectToPage, try the below code:

```
return RedirectToPage("/Account/Manage/ChangePassword");
```

`/Account/Manage/ChangePassword` means that we are looking for the ChangePassword.cshtml file in the Manage folder in the Account folder of the Pages folder.

```
return RedirectToPage("/Privacy");
```

`/Privacy` means that we are looking for the Privacy.cshtml file in the Pages  folder.

The RedirectToPage() method is referring to a Razor cshtml "page" rather than a html page in the browser. So it expects the parameter to refer to a cshtml page in your project.

**update:**
[image]

If you add in  IndexModel class to call page in Indentity folder you can try :

```
 public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            
            return RedirectToPage("/Account/Manage/ChangePassword", new { area = "Identity" });
        }
```

Comment: this not works. I got the same error with a different address: InvalidOperationException: No page named '/Account/Manage/ChangePassword' matches the supplied values.

Comment: @milad Please see my update. One way I add this at OnPostAsync in RegisterModel class to see the result. Second way I add this at OnGet in IndexModel class .